# How to call this tkinter gui function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, tkinter

How do i access windows function in Mygui class?
I want to create colored content in my tkinter box#
but i can't pass value to it.

```
      from tkinter import *
            class Mygui:
                def window(self, colour):
                    self.main_window=Tk()
                    self.main_window.geometry('300x100')
                    self.main_window.title('Login')
                    self.top_frame=Frame(self.main_window)
                    self.top_frame.pack()
                    self.label=Label(self.top_frame, fg=colour, text="Sample Text", width=45)
                    self.label.pack(side="top")
                    self.label1=Label(self.top_frame,text=" ", width=45)
                    self.label1.pack(side="top")
                    self.my_button = Button(self.main_window, text="Retry", command=self.do_something,  height=2, width=18)
                    self.my_button.pack()

                    mainloop()
                def do_something(self):
                    print('ok')

            class login:
                def example(self):
                    print("Start")
                    Mygui.window('blue')

            a = login.example(' ')
```

The error i get is:

```
  Start
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:/data/loginMech/test.py", line 25, in <module>
  a = login.example(' ')
  File "B:/data/loginMech/test.py", line 23, in example
  Mygui.window('blue')
  TypeError: window() missing 1 required positional argument: 'colour'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mygui` is a class, not a *function*. So, you have to construct an instance of it, like this:

```
gui = Mygui()
```

And then you can call methods on that instance:

```
gui.window('blue')
```

---

When you write `Mygui.window`, that's an unbound method, which you can call by explicitly passing it a `self` argument along with its other arguments. But you'd still need to have something to pass as that `self`:

```
gui = Mygui()
Mygui.window(gui, 'blue')
```

In general, you don't want to do this. There are cases where unbound methods are useful, but if you have one, you probably know you have one.

---

And you need to do the same thing with `login`:

```
log = login()
log.example()
```

By calling `login.example`, you're using an unbound method again. And then you're passing `' '` as the `self` argument. This doesn't make any sense, because `' '` is not a `login` instance, but CPython 3.x happens to not check for that error, so you get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

Abarnet pointed out one fix however in Tkinter it might be better to inherit from the Tkinter class `Tk` to start you GUI.

Take this example. A much smaller amount of code and produces the same results desired.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, colour):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('300x100')
        self.title('Login')
        tk.Label(self, fg=colour, text="Sample Text", width=45, pady=10).grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(self, text="Retry", command=self.do_something, height=2, width=18).grid(row=1, column=0)

    def do_something(self):
        print('ok')


MyGUI("Blue").mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]